# exposing secured tcp endpoint in aks

Tags: ssl, tcp, azure-aks, envoyproxy

there was a need of exposing a tcp endpoint that supports ssl termination in aks .

Azure's Load Balancer is a Layer 4 balancer and can balance TCP and UDP traffic. Therefor, it doesn't support SSL offloading.
Nginx ingress controller did not support our need since Kubernetes Ingress only supports services over HTTP and HTTPS , we can config nginx to pass tcp but it will not terminate ssl .

our solution was creating a sidecar container that takes care of the ssl termination and forwards every thing to our application , we chose envoy since it supports tls termination with  layer 4 communication  .

however this solution affects the system performance.
in a setup were aws LB controller is being used for ssl termination a performance test takes 40 ms to complete in the azure setup without envoy it takes the same time however with envoy it takes 80ms .
we are searching for a better solution that can expose the endpoint over tcp and can also be secure with ssl , if you know any better solutions or have any idea I would be happy to hear it .

we are searching for a better solution that can expose the endpoint over tcp and can also be secure with ssl , if you know any better solutions or have any idea I would be happy to hear it .

Comment: You might want to consider using the Application Gateway Ingress Controller [AGIC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-install-new). Create an Azure Application Gateway with an HTTPS listener. Update the AGIC configuration to point to your Application Gateway. Update your Ingress resource to include the necessary annotations for AGIC. By using AGIC, you can achieve SSL termination for your TCP endpoint while benefiting from Azure's managed service for application delivery.

Answer (score 0):

To expose a TCP endpoint with SSL termination in AKS using Azure Application Gateway, you'll need to follow these steps.

Create an AKS Cluster

```
az aks create --name yourAKSCluster --resource-group yourResourceGroup --node-count 2 --enable-addons monitoring --generate-ssh-keys
```

[image]

Create an Application Gateway using CLI

```
az network application-gateway create --name YourApplicationGateway --location eastus --resource-group YourResourceGroup --capacity 2 --sku Standard_v2 --http-settings-cookie-based-affinity Disabled --frontend-port 80 --http-settings-port 80 --http-settings-protocol Http --public-ip-address YourPublicIP
```

or you can do this via portal as well
[image]

Install AGIC in your AKS cluster. You can use Helm for this:

```
helm repo add ingress-azure https://appgwingress.blob.core.windows.net/ingress-azure-helm-package/
helm repo update
helm install ingress-azure/ingress-azure --name my-release --namespace ingress-basic --set appgw.name=MyApplicationGateway --set appgw.resourceGroup=MyResourceGroup --set appgw.subscriptionId=<subscription-id> --set appgw.shared=false --set armAuth.type=servicePrincipal --set armAuth.clientId=<client-id> --set armAuth.clientSecret=<client-secret> --set armAuth.tenantId=<tenant-id> --set kubernetes.watchNamespace=<namespace>
```

[image]

Create an Ingress resource to expose your application. Below is a simple Ingress definition:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: redis
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - <redis.contoso.com>
      secretName: <redis-secret-name>
  rules:
  - host: <redis.contoso.com>
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: frontend
          servicePort: 80
```

Deploy your application in AKS.
[image]

*'For SSL termination at the Application Gateway:'*
You need to create a Kubernetes secret for the certificate as below

```
kubectl create secret tls <guestbook-secret-name> --key <path-to-key> --cert <path-to-cert>
```

- Obtain an SSL certificate for your domain.
- Create a Kubernetes secret with your SSL certificate.
- Modify the Ingress resource to include the TLS termination.

Here is how you modify the Ingress for SSL:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: redis
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
spec:
  tls:
    - secretName: <redis-secret-name>
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: frontend
          servicePort: 80
```

This process sets up an Application Gateway as an ingress controller in AKS, which handles the SSL termination.

Reference document:
[MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-expose-service-over-http-https)